# I need to move my entire file system to another hard drive in Fedora

Tags: hard-drive, fedora, disk-space, migration

I'm using a computer with two internal hard drives, one is 500GB and the other is 30GB. My file system is stored on the 30GB and now it's full ( I can't even install updates ). I have plenty of space on my 500 GB hard drive, all I need to know is if there is a way to move the file system to the 500 GB Drive without causing any major problems to my operating system.

I'm on fedora 19